# Modify pagination script to show a different number of rows on the first page than the others

Tags: php, pagination

I have a simple pagination script:

```
$product_nr = count($query); // counts the number of products
$totalpages = ceil($product_nr / $rowsperpage);  
if ($currentpage > $totalpages){ $currentpage = $totalpages; } 
$offset = (($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage);
```

The code is set to show 20 rows per page -> $rowsperpage = 20;

I need an idea on how to show **only 18 rows on the first page ONLY** and add the remaining 2 rows to the $product_nr so it won't brake the 20 rows per page pagination for the other pages.

Basically:

```
1st page - 18 rows;
the other pages would show 20 rows per page from the remaining rows.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if possible you can set. $rowsperpage separately when on first page ie if $currentpage == 1 then $rowperpage=18
and for all other pages you'll have to set the offset -2
i.e

> if($currentpage != 1){  $offset = ((($currentpage - 1) *
>   $rowsperpage)) - 2 ; }

Answer (score 0):

```
if($currentpage == 1)
$rowsperpage = 18;
else
$rowsperpage = 20;
```